# how to create a wrapper for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been to this thread but not found my answer. 
[How to create a Wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024528/how-to-create-a-wrapper)

My question is how can I create a wrapper for jquery functions like jquery ajax and how does it work.

I would appreciate if someone can give a fiddle or a very simple example wrapping jquery ajax.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you expect the "$.ajax wrapper" to do?

Comment: I think, a script that will wrap $.ajax, so we will not call directly the $.ajax. I'm confuse about the wrapper.

Comment: Do you have a specific use-case? Is there a particular usage you have in mind?

Comment: I'll be using it to wrap the jquery functions by creating a wrapper, and the other developer will use the wrapper so they will not mind about the jqueries/dojo/etc.. behind that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I create a wrapper just using plain javascript not jquery codes?.
>   Thanks for the answer mate, it helps a lot

Like this?

```
var ajax = (function ($) {
    return function () {
        return $.ajax.apply($, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This question cannot really be answered without actually understanding why you want to create a *wrapper* and what you expect form this *wrapper*?

The `ajax` *wrapper* above will just be a function that delegates it's work to `$.ajax`. Basically as it is right now it's almost the same as doing `var ajax = $.ajax;`, the only difference being that the `this` value will be correctly bound to `$` when invoking `$.ajax`.

A *wrapper* can be many things, but most of the time it serves as an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) which is basically an object that offers a unified interface for incompatible objects.

`$.ajax` itself is the perfect example of this pattern since it deals with cross-browser issues such as browsers that doesn't support the standard `XMLHttpRequest` object.

You could also use a *wrapper* to mimic [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) features which can be really useful for cross-cutting concerns.

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper is useful if you're constantly doing the same things to modify an existing method. Suppose you use `$.get` a lot but you have to add a key to the data every time. Write a wrapper.

```
$.fn.extend({betterget: function(url, data, success, dataType) {
    data['key'] = 'foo';
    $.get(url, data, success, dataType);
}});
```

So you can change the calls from `$.get(...)` to `$.betterget(...)` and that popular key will always be set.

That's about all there is to it. There rest is up to your imagination and needs.

**edit**

"can I create a wrapper just using plain javascript not jquery codes?"

Sure:

```
function betterget(url, data, success, dataType) {
    data['key'] = 'foo';
    $.get(url, data, success, dataType);
}
```

This enables you to call `betterget` and it will do the jquery work for you.

Comment: can I create a wrapper just using plain javascript not jquery codes?. 

Thanks for the answer mate, it helps a lot.